# Spring Data JPA - ManyToMany - JPQL - @Query formation in Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a spring boot project with PostgreSQL RDBMS.
I have @ManyToMany relation between two entities - Customer & Product. They are joined by the customer_product. But while forming JPQL at repository layer, I am facing difficulties. Here is entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Customer.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Customer c")
public class Customer implements Serializable {

... all properties ... getter setter constructor...

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Product
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="customer_product"
        , joinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
            }
        , inverseJoinColumns={
            @JoinColumn(name="product_id")
            }
        )
    private List<Product> products;
```

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Product.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Product p")
public class Product implements Serializable {
... all properties ... getter setter ... constructors ...

//bi-directional many-to-many association to Customer
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="products")
    private List<Customer> customers;
```

Now at the repository later:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Integer> {

//Below mentioned query works perfectly as Customer & Address has OneToMany Relation

@Query("select new com.arindam.springjpa.springdatajpaexamples.vo.CustomerDetailsVO(c.id, c.customerName, a.fullAddress) from Customer c, Address a where c.address.addressId=a.addressId")
    List<CustomerDetailsVO> findAllCustomerDetails();

// But I need help on below query
// I want to find out full details of ManyToMany relation between customer & product

@Query("select new com.arindam.springjpa.springdatajpaexamples.vo.CustomerProductAddressDetailsVO(c.id, c.customerName, a.fullAddress, p.productName) from Customer c, Address a, Product p where c.address.addressId=a.addressId and c.products.product.productId=p.productId")

List<CustomerProductAddressDetailsVO> findAllCustomerAddressProductDetails();
```

To have results in VO here is simple VO class

```
@Entity
public class CustomerProductAddressDetailsVO {

    private Integer id;
    private String customerName;
    private String fullAddress;
    private String productName;

//Like a simple POJO with getter setter constructors
```

Can you please suggest.

Thanks for your valuable feedback.

Comment: You need to use joins (even for your first query). See https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join. The first query should actually look like `select new ... from Customer c join c.address`. I'll let you read the documentation and find out what the second one should be.

Comment: @JB Nizet - Many thanks. The first query works perfectly. But the second one has issues. The Second Query is ManyToMany, hence two List. So not able to make join.

Comment: What query have you tried, and what was the outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. Since the entity classes have been generated using Eclipse plugins, so the class for customer_product was not been generated. So I manually generated it and used the query. So the final code is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer_product")
@NamedQuery(name="CustomerProduct.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM CustomerProduct c")
public class CustomerProduct implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="customer_id")
    private Integer customerId;

    @Column(name="product_id")
    private Integer productId;
```

and Repository layer:

```
@Query("select new com.arindam.springjpa.springdatajpaexamples.vo.CustomerProductAddressDetailsVO(cp.id, c.customerName, a.fullAddress, p.productName) from Customer c, Address a, Product p, CustomerProduct cp "
            + "where c.address.addressId=a.addressId and cp.productId=p.productId and cp.customerId=c.id")
    List<CustomerProductAddressDetailsVO> findAllCustomerAddressProductDetails();
```

It works perfectly.